# Select values from a column into a pipe-delimited row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a column with some generic data and I want to present the data in a single, pipe-delimited row. The data:

```
ColumnA
========
asdfaa
asdf
```

Desired result:

```
asdfaa|asdf
```

Comment: Try Listagg() function.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368942/grouped-string-aggregation-listagg-for-sql-server

Hth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Result = STUFF((SELECT N'|' + ColumnA
    FROM dbo.[table]
    FOR XML PATH(''), 
        TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'');
```