# T-SQL How to GROUP BY two fields and concatenate another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to group on 2 fields and return a third field that is a concatenation of the values of another field that the first 2 have in common, with a given ProductID. Here is my data:

```
ProductID   Currency   Price   Territory
1           USD        6.99    US
1           EUR        4.99    GR
1           EUR        4.99    HU
1           EUR        4.99    LT
2           USD        7.99    US
2           EUR        5.99    GR
2           EUR        5.99    HU
```

I'd like results to come back like this:

```
ProductID   Currency   Price   Territories
1           USD        6.99    US
1           EUR        6.99    GR, HU, LT
```

I can pull the Currenty and Price columns, but can't concatenate the Territories they have in common:

```
SELECT Currency, Price
FROM TerritoryPricing
WHERE ProductID = 1
GROUP BY Currency, Price
```

How can I concatenate the territories?

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server aggregate string concatenation"

Comment: look this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368942/grouped-string-aggregation-listagg-for-sql-server

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL's XML processing to generate concatenated lists with SQL 2000 and up:

```
create table #TerritoryPricing ( ProductID int, Currency varchar(3), Price decimal(10,2), Territory varchar(2))
insert into #TerritoryPricing values (1,'USD',6.99,'US')
insert into #TerritoryPricing values (1,'EUR',4.99,'GR')
insert into #TerritoryPricing values (1,'EUR',4.99,'HU')
insert into #TerritoryPricing values (1,'EUR',4.99,'LT')
insert into #TerritoryPricing values (2,'USD',7.99,'US')
insert into #TerritoryPricing values (2,'EUR',5.99,'GR')
insert into #TerritoryPricing values (2,'EUR',5.99,'HU')

SELECT Currency, Price,
    SUBSTRING(
        (SELECT ( ',' + ltrim(rtrim(Territory)))  
        FROM #TerritoryPricing t2
        WHERE t1.Currency = t2.Currency  
            and t1.Price = t2.Price
            and ProductID = 1
        ORDER BY t2.Territory
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 2, 8000) Territories
FROM #TerritoryPricing t1
WHERE ProductID = 1
GROUP BY Currency, Price
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. The only thing I had to add was a "WHERE ProductID = 1" in the subquery WHERE clause. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use Concat:

```
SELECT ProductID, Currency, Price, CONCAT(Territory)
GROUP BY territory
FROM employee_tbl;
```

or create a function with colace something like like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[terr]
(
    @territoryID int
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @output varchar(max)
    select @output = COALESCE(@output + ', ', '') + territory
    from TerritoryPricing
    where territoryid = @territoryID

    return @output
END

GO

SELECT UserID, [dbo].terr(territoryID)
FROM TerritoryPricing
GROUP BY territory

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this code

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT 
    Currency, 
    Price , 
    Territories = (Select @S = @S  + Territory FROM TerritoryPricing as T2 WHERE T1.Currency = T2.Currency AND T1.Price = T2.Price) ,
    Empty = (select @S ='') 
FROM TerritoryPricing as T1
WHERE ProductID = 1
GROUP BY Currency, Price
```